# Unable to deploy streamlit : NameError: name 'GridOptionsBuilder' is not defined

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to deploy my streamlit .
I have included the requirements.txt file which includes steamlit-aggrid
[as attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDRaW.png).

error log : [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAouT.png)

Comment: Check your import if you have this. `from st_aggrid.grid_options_builder import GridOptionsBuilder`